# Desaparece la página al pulsar la flecha atrás del navegador

Tags: php, html, sesiones, back-button

Cuando navego entre las páginas mediante botones o siguiendo las indicaciones funciona correctamente, **el problema viene cuando quiero dar para "atrás" mediante la flecha** de la barra de direcciónes o *URL*. Me vuelve a la página anterior pero **no me recarga los datos**.

Me sale la **siguiente imagen** con esta información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si estoy en la página **confirmacion_reserva.php** y deseo ir para atrás mediante la flecha me tiene que cargar los datos de **reservar.php**, ¿Por qué no salen los datos de la página?

#### Mostraré los códigos de ambas páginas eliminando información innecesaria para que sea mas legible.

**confirmacion_reserva.php**

```
<?php
include_once "Clases/BD.php";

//Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
session_start();

//Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
    $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Confirmación reserva</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_confirmacion.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        //Guardamos en una variable de sesión las fechas, entrada y salida.
        $_SESSION["check_in"] = $_POST["check_in"];
        $_SESSION["check_out"] = $_POST["check_out"];
        $_SESSION["personas"] = $_POST["personas"];
        $_SESSION["pago_total"] = $_POST["pago_total"];
        $_SESSION["idcabana"] = $_POST["idcabana"];

        //Si no existe la variable de sesión...     
        if(!isset($_SESSION["cliente"])){
            header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
        //Si existe la variable de sesión...
        }else{
            //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "Reservar"...
            if(isset($_POST["reservar"])){
                $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"];
                $idemail = $_SESSION["cliente"];
                $check_in = $_SESSION["check_in"];
                $check_out = $_SESSION["check_out"];
                $personas = $_SESSION["personas"];
                $pago_total = $_SESSION["pago_total"];
                $modo_pago = "TARJETA";
            ?>
            <form action="pago.php" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST">
            <?php
                echo "<div id='detalles_reserva'>";
                echo 
                    "<img src='imagenes/cabaña.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabaña: ".$idcabana."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/email.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email: ".$idemail."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='check_in'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_in: ".$check_in."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt=check_out'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_out: ".$check_out."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/personas.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='personas'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Personas: ".$personas."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/euros.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='pago_total'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Pago total: ".$pago_total."€
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<input type='submit' name='mireserva' id='mireserva' value='REALIZAR PAGO'>";
                echo "</div>";
            ?>
            </form>
            <?php
            }else{
                //Si recargamos la página perdemos los datos, así que volvamos al inicio: "reservar.php".
                unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**reservar.php**

```
<?php
    include_once "Clases/BD.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
        $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
    }

    //Si nos hemos salido de la sesión del administrador, destruimos la sesión.
    if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
       //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "administrador".
       unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
       //session_destroy();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="sesion_cliente">
            <?php 
            //Si existe la sesión "cliente"...
            if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                echo "<p class='negrita'>Bienvenido <a href='menu_cliente.php?nueva=1#nueva'>".$cliente."</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='reservar.php?salir=1'>Salir</a></p>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                    unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                    //Redireccionamos a la página "iniciar_sesion_cliente.php" en 0 segundos.
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="busqueda">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                    <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                    <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

                    <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                    <p id="calculoNoches"></p><br/>

                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
                if(isset($_POST["buscar"]) && $_POST["check_in"]!="" && $_POST["check_out"]!=""){
                    $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
                    $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
                    $datos = BD::obtenerCabanasPorFecha($check_in, $check_out);
                    echo "<br/>";
                    foreach($datos as $cabana){
                        //..................Informacion innecesaria para este problema..............
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Lo que sucede es que tu flujo fue el siguiente: index -> post reserva.php -> post confirmacion_reserva.php. En este último al colocar atrás el explorador intenta llevarte a "post reserva.php" Es decir a reserva.php pero no solo, si no con el estado que estaba cuando pasaste por ahí (que fue un POST). Ya que el explorador sabe que no es lo mismo para una página mostrarse con datos POST que sin datos POST, en el fondo intenta devolverte no solo a la página anterior, sino que también al estado en el que se encontraba, eso es por lo siguiente: No es lo mismo ir por ejemplo a user.php con post id=10, que ir a user.php con post id=5, que ir a user.php sin post.

El explorador sabe que los datos POST son relevantes para lo que vas a mostrar, por eso te solicita un reenviar los datos. Esto sucede solo con POST y no con GET debido a que POST tiene mayores medidas de seguridad, por ejemplo con esto el explorador evita que vayas a ingresar dos veces un registro, si apretaras atrás a reserva_guardar.php, por ejemplo. En cambio con GET solo te manda para atrás, ya que espera que no estés guardando datos con ese método.

En resumen este es un problema de cómo estás enviando los datos y cómo estás estructurando tus archivos, te recomendaría pasar los datos por GET cuando quieras que puedan apretar atrás, y mandarlos por POST solo cuando vayas a guardarlos. Recordando que GET es menos seguro que POST siempre claro. También puedes deshabilitar el botón atrás con Javascript.

También te recomendaría usar un Framework PHP, estás pasando por un montón de tedio innecesario, te ahorrarás varias horas y probablemente el código será más escalable y tendrá un mejor desempeño.

Espero haber sido de ayuda,
¡Saludos y éxito!

**Actualización**

Después de ahondar en el problema en comentarios, en concreto el código queda así:

```
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="busqueda">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="GET" class="form_buscar">
    <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
    <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['check_in'])){ echo $_GET['check_in']; }?>">

     <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['check_out'])){ echo $_GET['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

     <p id="calculoNoches"></p><br/>

     <div align="center">
       <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>

 <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
            <?php
            //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
            if(isset($_GET["buscar"]) && $_GET["check_in"]!="" && $_GET["check_out"]!=""){
                $check_in = $_GET["check_in"];
                $check_out = $_GET["check_out"];
                $datos = BD::obtenerCabanasPorFecha($check_in, $check_out);
                echo "<br/>";
                foreach($datos as $cabana){
                    //..................Informacion innecesaria para este problema..............
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Me parece, ahora entiendo. Esto: <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar"> cambialo a GET y dejarás de tener el problema (Tendrás que cambiar tus $_POST a $_GET también en el mismo archivo).

Comment: Publícalo como respuesta para que los demás usuarios puedan participar, y si funciona aceptar tu respuesta válida. Haz una respuesta con el código.